# Finding the matrix of the linear transformation defined by $\mbox{L}(f) = \frac{\partial^2\!f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\!f}{\partial y^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation $L: V_n \to V_{n-2}$ where

$$V_n = \{ a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1}y + \ldots + a_ny^n : a_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

i.e. the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in two variables $x$ and $y$.

$L$ is defined by: $$\mbox{L}(f) = \frac{\partial^2\!f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\!f}{\partial y^2}$$

There is an obvious basis for $V_n$:

$$\mathcal{B_n} = \{x^n, x^{n-1}y,\;\ldots\;,xy^{n-1},y^n\}$$

I am having trouble finding the matrix of $L$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}_n$ and $\mathcal{B}_{n-2}$. I know that because:

$$x^n \to n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
$$x^{n-1}y \to (n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}y$$
$$x^{n-2}y^2 \to (n-2)(n-3)x^{n-4}y^2 + 2x^{n-2}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$y^n \to n(n-1)y^{n-2}$$

The matrix I'm looking for looks sort of like this:

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
n(n-1) & 0 & 2 & \ldots \\
0 & (n-1)(n-2) & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & (n-2)(n-3) & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

But how can I describe that matrix, and what is its rank?

Answer (score 0):

In general, given an operator $L$ and a basis $e_j$ the matrix representation of $L$ (which I will call $L_{i,j}$) in the basis $e_j$ is given by

$$
L e_j = \sum_i  L_{i,j} e_i
$$

This is because, since $e_j$ is a basis, each vector $L e_j$ can be expressed in a unique way as a linear combination of $e_j$. Note the order of the label $i$ in the above equation. It is so chosen such that the composition of operators becomes standard matrix multiplication according to the usual (row-column) convention.

Now the domain $V_n$ and the range $V_{n-2}$ are really different things (an homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ is mapped to an homogeneous polynomial of degree $n-2$). In particular $V_n$ has dimension $n+1$ and $V_{n-2}$ has dimension $n-1$ so you will get an $(n+1)\times (n-1)$ matrix $L_{i,j}$.

The rank is the dimension of the image, in this case the whole $V_{n-2}$ so its rank is..?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of describing the matrix, start by giving it a name - let's call it $A$, and call its elements $a_{i,j}$. Then, using the information you've included, you can describe the elements - for example, you've found that $a_{i,i}=(n+1-i)(n-i)$. Just need to describe the other elements as well.

As for rank, that's a different question - start by thinking about the possible outputs after applying the transformation, or any outputs in $V_{n-2}$ that you might not be reachable.